# Subtracting hours from date string

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

I am working in node js and by using moment-timezone [package](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) I have generated a date:

2017-4-10 19:04:47

Below is the code I used to generate this date time which is for timezone Asia/shanghai:

```
var momentTimezone = require('moment-timezone');
console.log(momentTimezone(new Date()).tz('Asia/shanghai').format('Y-M-D HH:MM:ss'));
```

Now I want to subtract hours from this time to generate another date. I want to subtract 9940 hours.

I have searched for many hours but could not find exact solution.

Below is the python code which I have to replicate:

```
 end_time = datetime.now(g.china) 
 //g.china =   timezone("Asia/Shanghai")
 begin_time = end_time - timedelta(hours=9940)
```

Any guidance over this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: convert both to millisecond subtract and then read the new date this would be subtracting 24 hours from current date "new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) - (24*60*60*1000));"

Comment: the docs of moment.js (they're same both client / server side) tells how to subtract 9940 hours (that's a lot ...) [`Moment.js docs - Subtract`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) . check the table in "add" for the right keys.

Comment: In the front page of Moment web site I can read stuff like `moment().subtract(10, 'days')` :-?

Comment: @KarelG does moment accept timezone? Because I want to have shanghai time i.e CST.

Comment: @Simer moment uses a plugin for that: [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) which reads and converts from/to timezones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use moment [`subtract`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) method.

Here a working sample:

```js
// Current time in Shanghai
var m = moment.tz('Asia/Shanghai');
console.log(m.format('Y-M-D HH:mm:ss'));
// Subtract 9940 hours
console.log(m.subtract(9940, 'hours').format('Y-M-D HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you should use lowercase `mm` to show minutes because uppercase `MM` represents months. See [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) tokens.