# set a time interval based on current date Object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, api, date, datetime

So I am currently using the Google Calendar API, specifically the freebusy query (as seen here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query).

The request body requires a 'timeMin' and 'timeMax'. And here comes my question...

How would I set these two values dynamically based off the current *datetime*. Basically use the current *datetime* to set an interval, say an hour before now, and an hour after now.

I have seen other stackoverflow posts ([Subtracting hours from date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322526/subtracting-hours-from-date-string)) on how to setHours by getHours but the problem with this method seems to be that it alters the current time instead of creating a new instance.

Also I need to keep the resulting min and max *datetimes* in ISOstring format (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) because this is what is used in Google Calendar API request body.

[image: Chrome DevTools Console]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
var now = new Date();
var msNow = now.getTime();  //  total mil1iseconds since 1970/01/01
var timeMax = new Date(msNow + 60 * 60 * 1000); //  "now" plus one hour
var timeMin = new Date(msNow - 60 * 60 * 1000); //  "now" minus one hour
console.log(now);
console.log(timeMin);
console.log(timeMax);
```

Comment: very interesting, thank you for the lightning quick response wow! I was not creating new Date objects for the min and max, which was why I was overwriting the current time. Thanks Oleksandr for clarifying so simply.